# How proceeded author from $(3)$ to get $a_n<f(n)-f(0)<1$

Tags: calculus

We have $f:(-1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ and $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)-\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$

We need to prove that $a_n$ is bounded.

> I don't need another method, I want to help strictly on subject

---

Here is all my steps:

$$\tag 1 \int_0^1 f(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k-1}^k f(x)dx$$
$$\tag 2 f'(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}>0\Rightarrow\:f\:is\:strictly\:increasing$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$: $$\tag 3 \Rightarrow\int_0^1 f(x)dx>\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k-1)$$

$$\Rightarrow -f(0)-f(n-1)>a_n$$

$$\Rightarrow a_n<-(1-\frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0,\:when\:n\rightarrow\infty$$

> -But from $(3)$ the author from my book said that $a_n<f(n)-f(0)<1$;
>
> -I want to know if my solution after $(3)$ is good how proceed author to get $a_n<f(n)-f(0)<1$;
>
> -My solution is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (3) you have
\begin{split}
a_n & = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) - \int_0^1 f(x) dx \\
& = f(n) - f(0) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k) - \int_0^1 f(x) dx \\
& = f(n) - f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k-1) - \int_0^1 f(x) dx \\
& < f(n) - f(0)
\end{split}

Comment: From $(3)$ I have $\int_0^1 f(x)dx>\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k-1)$ how do you get what you wrote from here?

Comment: It is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k-1) - \int_0^1 f(x)dx < 0$ and therefore $f(n) - f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^n f(k-1) - \int_0^1 f(x)dx < f(n) - f(0)$. This shows the implication from (3) to the next line in your post may have something wrong.

Comment: why you prove that $f(n) - f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k-1) - \int_0^1 f(x) dx < f(n) - f(0)$ ?

Comment: Because the left hand side is $a_n$. I try to match the terms as you got from (3). $a_n$ involves $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ and in (3) you have $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k-1)$. $f(n) - f(0)$ is the difference between them.

Comment: is something wrong in my solution?

Comment: I think there is, and it is the line right after (3). Would you elaborate how you get $-f(0) - f(n-1) > a_n$, like I explain $f(n) - f(0) > a_n$?

Comment: of course, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)+f(0)+f(n-1)$$ After that move $f(0)+f(n-1)$ in the left hand and you'll get what I wrote

Comment: Nope. Right hand side has $n+2$ positive terms and left hand side has $n$ only. There is one more $f(n-1)$ and $f(n)$ on the right. As I said in the comments above, it should be $$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) - f(n) + f(0) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) - (f(n) - f(0))$$

Comment: You can try for example $n=2$. You left hand side is $f(0) + f(1)$ and your right hand side is $f(1)+f(2)+f(0)+f(1)$.

Comment: indeed you've right SRX...but I can't explain why isn't correct because $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)+f(0)+f(n-1)=f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)+f(0)+f(n-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n f(k-1)$

Comment: What is ideea on which is based this sum?

Comment: Because there is already one $f(n-1)$ in $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$, you don't need one more. And $f(n)$ is redundant for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)$. Just think of the simple case $f(x) = x$: what is the difference between $1+2+\ldots+n$ and $0+1+2+\ldots+(n-1)$? The first one has one more $n$ and the second one has one more $0$. How to match them? Removing $n$ and add $0$ to the first expression becomes the second.

Comment: To me the trick of summation is just looking at the number of terms and not missing the terms you need. It is kind of intuition more or less.

Comment: now I understand, so the most important thing is to have the same number of terms